Convert json to a another json
We have a requirement where we need to convert json from one source/tool to another source.
That would involve
a. mapping attributes
b. change in hierarchy
c. dropping few attributes.
*The json's are pretty complex with lot of hierarchies involved
I am skeptical for writing custom code. What is the best industry practices for solving such problems ?
For tools, I am exploring ones which have java support.
